# How to create Multi Item Fab in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, floating-action-button

I need to know how to create a Multi-Item FAB, I have already tried https://compose.academy/blog/building_a_multi-action_floating_action_button_in_jetpack_compose. but this will not fulfill my requirement as the translucent background only covers the content Area not the top and bottom bar area. I cannot Use Dialog either as it draws over the FAB.

[image]
I am adding Google Docs' multi action Fab for reference

Comment: Add the images you need to create.

Comment: @alekseyHunter Check the reference Image I have added.

Comment: "this will not fulfill my requirement" -- you might want to consider adding a [mcve] showing what you tried and showing the results.

Comment: Ok, so what do you get in the Preview?